# Error when opening lunar SAR data

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I am working on Lunar SAR data and when opening the raster (.tif) in QGIS shows me distorted image with the following error:

No transform is available between Unknown CRS: GEOGCRS["Moon Spheroid",DATUM["Moon_Spheroid",ELLI… and Unknown CRS: GEOGCRS["unknown",DATUM["unknown",ELLIPSOID["WGS 8….
proj_create_operations: Source and target ellipsoid do not belong to the same celestial body

[image]

Zoomed image:

[image]

I also have an Excel sheet with Lat, long information of all pixels, but don,t know how can I make use of it.

[image]

How to resolve the error and visualize the data properly?

Google drive link to some data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uRZNFh3774BxDAE2rEqWthwx0oxuieLz/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

EPSG:4326 is an Earth based projection, so transforming Lunar data to it is not a good idea.

You need to set your project CRS to either your data CRS or another projection designed for Lunar data such as ESRI:104903.